# Check if file exist in one folder, if not copy it and rename it. (tricky timestamp in name)

Tags: bash, shell, date, sed

I want to check if awstats**012021**.blalblalblala.txt is in my directory, if it is I want to rename it to awstats**012021**.blalblalblala-**main**.txt.

How can I check that with all this files and also when there are coming new ones. I always want to rename (copy) it with a -main.txt version. Especially if you have to consider the date in the title.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   9233 Apr  7 17:08 awstats012021.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   9233 Mar  1 14:25 awstats012021.blalblalblala.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  12986 Mar  2 00:00 awstats022021.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  12986 Mar  2 00:00 awstats022021.blalblalblala.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  37865 Apr  2 00:00 awstats032021.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  37865 Apr  2 00:00 awstats032021.blalblalblala.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  16036 Apr  7 00:00 awstats042021.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  23983 Apr 13 00:00 awstats042021.blalblalblala.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   9463 Mar  1 14:25 awstats112020.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   9463 Mar  1 14:25 awstats112020.blalblalblala.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  21645 Mar  1 14:25 awstats122020.blalblalblala-main.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  21645 Mar  1 14:25 awstats122020.blalblalblala.txt
```

awstats and blalblablala are fix strings. Only the number 012021 aren't, it's always month and then the year. So we need a wildcard. I only need to check in one directory. I think in this example it's possible also for zero files matching, but when a new file called "awstats052021.blalblalblala.txt" will created, I want to automatically rename it to "awstats052021.blalblalblala-main.txt".

```
for awstats??????.blalblalblala.txt in /srv/www/example/storage/logs/awstats
                if not exist awstats??????.blalblalblala-main.txt
                               cp -p awstats??????.blalblalblala.txt awstats??????.blalblalblala-main.txt
                not if 
                echo "no file to copy!"

exit
```

Comment: Rename is not the same as copy; you have to make up your mind.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: I assumed you want to rename the files, hence the use of `mv`.
> Replace with `cp` if you want copies.  Your question is confusing on
> that point.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/srv/www/example/storage/logs/awstats"

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename
do
    # get the filename without the extension
    filename_noext=${filename%.txt}
    # new filename has -main added to it, plus the extension
    newfilename="${filename_noext}-main.txt"

    # if the newfilename does not exist, create it from the original file (mv deletes that original file)
    if [[ ! -f "$newfilename" ]]
    then
        echo "Changing file $filename to $newfilename"
        mv $filename $newfilename
    else
        echo "File $newfilename already exists"
    fi
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -name "awstats*.blalblalblala.txt" -print0)
```

Details:

- `find` uses the `-print0` option to delimit every file found with a \0 char.
- `read` uses the `-d $'\0'` option to read each filename, using \0 as the delimiter between filenames.
- This ensure that files with spaces are still processed properly.  It was not strictly required in your situation, but it is always better to show examples which are the most general as possible.  See this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for a complete discussion.
- `find` uses the `-name` option to specify which files to process.  In your question, all files start with "awstats" and end with ".blalblalblala.txt" so a simple `*` suffices.
- `${filename%.txt}` uses bash variable expansion to remove the extention ".txt" form the filename.

That script will therefore rename every file awstat*.blalblalblala.txt to the same with -main added.

Now if you want to make it automatically run when new files are created, you have two options:

1. use `cron` and run it at fix time intervals (ex. every 5 minutes).
2. if you require quasi-realtime, have a look at `inotify`.  More complex, only go this route if you **have** to react quickly to files creation.